# ItemsControl - Grid child elements auto resize

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I'm using Rachel Lim's [GridHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007442/1462911) to get dynamic number of rows. What I wanted to achieve is to have each row displayed one below another (done), to be able to resize them (done - using GridSplitter) and to have content resized proportionally to the screen size.

Result:

[image]

What I would like to have:
[image]

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RowSource}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid local:GridHelper.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowNumber}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 2" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 3" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Btn" />
                    </Grid>
                    <GridSplitter Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
internal class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<RowInfo> RowSource { get; set; }

    public int RowCount { get { return RowSource.Count; } }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        RowSource = new ObservableCollection<RowInfo>()
        {
            new RowInfo() { RowNumber = 0 },
            new RowInfo() { RowNumber = 1 },
            new RowInfo() { RowNumber = 2 }
        };
    }
}
```

**RowInfo:**

```
public class RowInfo
{
    public int RowNumber { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I get the question well, what you want is that the rows by default should have some height even if there is no content in them. Is that what's the need?

Comment: Yes, I want rows to be resized proportionally to window size. @mm8 got that part right but resizing (with GridSplitter) stopped to work correctly.

Comment: Oh so basically, you want the content to be spread across the whole view and when I resize the window then you want to scale the rows and columns as well?

Comment: Exactly. But also I want to use GridSplitter to resize each row individually.

Comment: Well I see. I'll try to write up a control.

Comment: Is the data contained in `RowSource` truly changeable and dynamic and it grows/shrinks?  Or in reality there would be no more than non changing five static items? In other words are there actual limitation totals of the actual data which will be used?

Comment: Also why does it have to be a datagrid? If it is only a line of data, why not create a custom layout of textboxes of headers/data?

Comment: RowSource is dynamic. I have removed irrelevant part of that code so that I can paste it on SO. I don't have problem with DataGrid but with Grid. I want to have content of grid spread across whole view and to be able to resize each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is all wrong. You cannot use an `ItemsControl`, as the `GridSplitter` items need to be at the `ItemsPanel` level rather than in the `DataTemplate` - otherwise, it won't work.

You are better off using a custom behavior on the Grid Itself - see example code below:

```cs
public class GridAutoRowChildBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(GridAutoRowChildBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGridPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(GridAutoRowChildBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGridPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnGridPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((GridAutoRowChildBehavior) d).ResetGrid();
    }

    private void ResetGrid()
    {
        var source = ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (source == null || ItemTemplate == null)
            return;
        AssociatedObject.Children.Clear();
        AssociatedObject.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var content = new ContentPresenter
            {
                ContentTemplate = ItemTemplate,
                Content = item
            };
            var splitter = new GridSplitter
            {
                Height = 5,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
            };
            AssociatedObject.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            Grid.SetRow(content,count);
            Grid.SetRow(splitter,count);
            AssociatedObject.Children.Add(content);
            AssociatedObject.Children.Add(splitter);
            count++;
        }

    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }


    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you code it up like this:

```
<Grid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:GridAutoRowChildBehavior ItemsSource="{Binding RowsSource}">
            <local:GridAutoRowChildBehavior.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <DataGrid>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 2" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 3" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Btn" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:GridAutoRowChildBehavior.ItemTemplate>
        </local:GridAutoRowChildBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

I have tested this and it works exactly as you need.

The only additional thing you need to do is add the Nuget package `Systems.Windows.Interactivity.WPF` to your project

Comment: Great work Dean! Where can I read more about interactivity library in depth?

Comment: this is a good starting point https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195669(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just a small update for someone that might read this: if you have Behavior inside ItemControl (like I have but it is not shown in this sample) you have to override OnAttached and call ResetGrid inside of it.
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            ResetGrid();
        }
Also check if AssociatedObject is null inside ResetGrid method.

Answer (score 0):

Use star-sizing for the `RowDefintions` that you created in the `GridHelper` class:

```
public static void RowCountChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(obj is Grid) || (int)e.NewValue < 0)
        return;

    Grid grid = (Grid)obj;
    grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.NewValue; i++)
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(
            new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }); //<--

    SetStarRows(grid);
}
```

And set the `Height` of your first `RowDefinition` to `*`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Yellow">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 2" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 3" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Btn" />
            </Grid>
            <GridSplitter Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That does make content resize proportionally but resizing is not working correctly then.

Comment: what do you mean about `resizing`?

Comment: I want to use GridSplitter to resize Row(s).

Comment: I want the content to be spread across the whole view and when I resize the window then you want to scale the rows and columns as well.
And also I want to use GridSplitter to resize each row individually.